# Will innodb record undo log redo log when not enable transaction?

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb

AFAIK, Undo log and Redo log are used to realize transaction operation in Innodb of Mysql. However, I'm curious about whether  innodb will record undo log redo log or not when not enabling transaction?

Comment: Why are you tagging `sql-server` (Microsoft SQL Server)? innodb is all about MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

When you have `autocommit=ON` and the command(s) are not in `BEGIN...COMMIT`, each SQL write is considered to be a transaction unto itself.  Think of it as an *implicit* `BEGIN...COMMIT`.

A prime example of it is a big `UPDATE` that is changing thousands of rows.  With the implicit transaction, even a power failure after changing only some of the rows will lead to a `ROLLBACK` (implicit) after the server comes back up.  (Without that, the table would be in a very unpredictable state.)

A `TEMPORARY TABLE`, on the other hand, does not need ACID protection.  Depending on what version you are using, a new optimization may avoid writing to undo/redo logs for such tables.

Comment: what if `autocommit=ON` is not opened? Will undo and redo log be enabled?

Comment: @choxsword - =OFF  won't save any results until you do `COMMIT`.  So effectively it is one long transaction (with undo/redo.

Comment: what if I never use any commands related to transaction, like commit, and just run raw simple statements?

Comment: @choxsword - The default is, I think, `AUTOCOMMIT=ON`, so each write query will be effectively a separate transaction, involving the undo/redo logs.  It works, it is all good.  Live with it.  Perhaps most MySQL apps are doing just that.  I would use multiple statements in an explicit transaction for things like banking apps.  (Eg: take money out of one account and put it into another. --> 2 writes inside BEGIN...COMMIT)